# Sharepoint online archive Options

Tags: sharepoint-online, archive, sharepoint-2016

I want to know the out of the box Sharepoint online archive Options.

1. If we want to move Sharepoint on-premises sites to Sharepoint online archive what and all options are there ?
2. Is there any 3-rd party tool ?
3. Possible to move Azure blob ?

Can you provide me the available options in Sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions available like one drive achieving etc.
migrating from on-Prem to SharePoint online, you can use share gate but it is expensive.
do you want to migrate only documents or sites including lists etc? If yes then what will be the retrieval frequency?